# .NET 6 Impersonate issue

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm creating a web app and a Web API under .NET 6 using C#. Windows identity is enabled on both IIS websites.

My issue is I'm getting error "401 Unauthorized". In IIS Log, I also see that error number : #2148074252.

```
var userToImpersonate = (WindowsIdentity)_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity;

WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(
    userToImpersonate.AccessToken, () =>
    {
        var uri = new Uri("...");

        string responseString;

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                responseString = client.GetStringAsync(uri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Please note, that impersonate code works in local, and others development servers. I'm also using same technique in .NET 4.8 with success.

Comment: why don't you try logging userToImpersonate.Name to make sure you are running as the identity you think you are

Comment: Have you configured Windows Authentication  correctly in IIS settings? Because, windows authentication confiuration is crucial on both WebApp and WebApi within IIS. In addition, Have you checked Service Principal Names (SPN)? Is there anything logged about double-hop issues? Your configuration and other setup need to check to investigate the issue.

Comment: Rob Sedgwick I already did that.  I simplified to maximum the code here to show only relevant lines.

Comment: Md Farid Uddin Kiron I think yes.  Windows Auth is enabled, and providers are NTLM and Negotiate.  Windows auth is working well from all client, except when calls are made from the that webapp.  What to check (and how) with the SPN?

Comment: "Is there anything logged about double-hop issues?"  Can you tell me more about this?

Comment: Yeah sure, a double-hop issue occurs when multiple authentication attempts happen within one transaction, causing Kerberos authentication to fail. This typically involves impersonation, where one system acts on behalf of another user. For [`SPN` please check this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc731241(v=ws.11))